# ¿Apuntar el dominio a otro hosting afectará al posicionamiento SEO de mi página?

Tags: web, hosting, seo, dominio

Actualmente tengo apuntado mi dominio con el hosting de Hostinger, pero estoy planeando cambiarme a Byethost. Sin embargo, mantengo el posicionamiento SEO de mi página, por lo que al buscar mi sitio web en Google éste es el primero que suele aparecer.

Mi duda es si al apuntar mi dominio al hosting nuevo afectará o no sustancialmente al posicionamiento actual que tiene el SEO de Google y Bing para con mi sitio web. Y caso de que sea positivo, ¿qué se podría hacer para prevenir el configurar de nueva cuenta el SEO?

De antemano, muchas gracias por sus respuestas. Saludos y buen día.

Comment: La manera como te tienen rankeado los buscadores depende de tu dominio, no de tu hosting. Si el dominio ahora se resuelve hacia otra máquina, a los buscadores les da igual. Lo único que podría cambiar es que haya una variación en los tiempos de respuesta. Un hosting más rápido te hará rankear mejor, y viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

Google rankea las páginas por su URL (dominio), es por eso que debes tener mucho cuidado al migrar a otro hosting ya que no debes tener errores de vinculación del dominio a las páginas (si usas WordPress recuerda chequear los permalinks).

Si uno de los enlaces no funciona será penalizado por el algoritmo de Google.

Si has realizado la migracion de manera correcta no deberías tener problemas ya que Google no ve en que hosting la tienes alojada, pero como he dicho anteriormente, revisa si no hay links rotos.

Saludos cordiales!

Comment: Hola, hice el cambio de hosting finalmente hace unos 3 meses y al parecer la búsqueda en Google y Bing no se vieron afectados. Muchas gracias por el dato.